# cakephp hasone and belongs join not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo, orm

I have two tables:

- **users** contains (id, name, email) `id` is the primary key.
- **users_details** contains (user_id, address, city, postcode) `user_id` is the foreign key to user table.

The `users.id=users_details.user_id`.

I wrote user model like this in **User.php**

```
class User extends AppModel {

public $name = 'User';
public $displayField = 'name';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    var $belongsTo = 'UsersDetail';
    public $hasone = array(
    'UsersDetail' => array(
        'className' => 'UsersDetail',           
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
                    'foreignKey' => 'id',
        'order' => '',
                    'dependent' => true
      )
  );   
}
```

I wrote the usersdetail model in **UsersDetail.php**

```
class UsersDetail extends AppModel {

public $name = 'UsersDetail';
public $displayField = 'name';        

    public $belongsTo = array( 'User' =>  
       array( 'className' => 'User','foreignKey' => 'user_id') );

    public $hasone = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',          
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
                    'foreignKey' => 'id',
        'order' => '',
                    'dependent' => true
    ));
}
```

I want to get the data from table using the join with condition. The `users.id=users_details.user_id`.

Comment: You need to choose one relationship per model AND uniquely name it. Does more than 1 UserDetail exist per User?

Comment: I am new to it. Can you explain me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared two relationships for each model association, when you should only have one going each way.

Like so: 
In the userDetail Model:

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'

        )
    );
```

And consequently, in the User Model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'UserDetail' => array(
            'className' => 'UserDetail',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

Check out the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) for more details.

Comment: Sorry Boss, I couldn't get the result.The query output I get is. "SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`mobile`, `User`.`pswd`, `UserDetail`.`user_id`, `UserDetail`.`address`, `UserDetail`.`city`, `UserDetail`.`state`, `UserDetail`.`postcode`, `UserDetail`.`dob`, `UserDetail`.`photo` FROM `cakedemo`.`users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `cakedemo`.`users_details` AS `UserDetail` ON (`User`.`user_id` = `UserDetail`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1". it must be (`User`.`id` = `UserDetail`.`user_id`)

Answer (score 0):

- **user** has (id, name, email) id is the primary key.
- users_details has(user_id, address, city, postcode) user_id is the foreign key to user table. Means.

**Point to remember:**

- **one to one relation** - **hasOne** -   A **user table** has one **users_detail**.
- belongto - A **userdetails table** belongs to **User** table.

So, the relation between the two tables is hasone and belongsto.

find the right code below.

> User model:

```
public $hasOne = array('UsersDetail' => array(
                       'className' => 'UsersDetail',
                       'foreignKey' => 'user_id')
                       );
```

> UsersDetail model

```
public $belongsTo = array('User' => array(
                          'className' => 'Users',
                          'foreignKey' => 'id',
                          'conditions' => '',
                          'fields' => '',
                          'order' => '')
                          );
```

which provide the join precisely. You can add the conditions, order in collections.

**The output query**

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`mobile`, `User`.`pswd`, `UsersDetail`.`user_id`, `UsersDetail`.`address`, `UsersDetail`.`city`, `UsersDetail`.`state`, `UsersDetail`.`postcode`, `UsersDetail`.`dob`, `UsersDetail`.`photo` FROM `cakedemo`.`users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `cakedemo`.`users_details` AS `UsersDetail` ON (`UsersDetail`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1
```

Thank you,